# show balloon at element after x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to show a balloon over a html element after x seconds have passed, without any needed actions from the user. I tried it like the following code example, but this does not work like expected. The code just enables the balloon after `2000 ms`, so if the user hovers over the element after this time, then he will see a balloon.

My goal is to show the balloon after x seconds, without the user having to hover over the element, the balloon should just show no matter where the mouse is pointing at.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myelement').balloon({
      position: "bottom", 
      contents: "Show a message.", 
      css: { color: "red"}
    });
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#myelement {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/urin/jquery.balloon.js/master/jquery.balloon.js"></script>

<div id="myelement">
  <h1>TEST</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just bound the event after 2000ms. But it only shows the tooltip after hovering over the element. Because of this you first have to call your ballon plugin and bind the event to the element. If it is ready, just trigger the bound event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Activate Plugin
  $('#myelement').balloon({position: "bottom", contents: "Show a message.", css: { color: "red"}});

  // Set delay and run event
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myelement').trigger('mouseenter');
  }, 2000);
});
```